# Gimp fill area with glowing effect near boundary

Tags: gimp

I am looking for tutorial website for below effect. Fill an area with a color. But at the boundary, the color is slighter, i.e. transition.

I dont know how to describe the effect. Please have a look at attached image.

[image]

Comment: Use the wand tool (`U`), select the area you want to fill. Then use the bucket tool (`Shift-B`), fill it with white. Then from the right click menu do `select -> feather` and enter a value of 15 or 20 pixels or so. Then, still using the bucket tool, fill it with red. I'm pretty sure this question is off-topic here, by the way.

Comment: exactly what I want, thank you so much!

Comment: [no problem](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/when-should-no-problem-replace-youre-welcome-as-a-response-to-thank-you) ;)